# Derivative of $h(x,t)=g\left(\frac{x}{t^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please explain me the method to get the partial derivative of a function like:

> $h(x,t)=g\left(\frac{x}{t^2}\right)$ where $g$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

I know that if we have a function $f(x(t,s),y(t,s))$ then
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$.

Also I can see that the given function $h$ can be written as a composition of two functions as follows:
For $g_1(x.t)=\frac{x}{t^2}$. So that, $$h(x,t)=g(g_1(x,t)).$$
But I really cannot see how to use them to partially differentiate $h$.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you mean $h(x,t)$ or $g(x/y^2)?$

Comment: Note that in your $\partial f/ \partial t$ you are assuming $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, but your post does not imply that for the variable $x$ in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=g'(g_1(x,t))\cdot \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}(x,t)=g'\left(\frac{x}{t^2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=g'(g_1(x,t))\cdot \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial t}(x,t)=g'\left(\frac{x}{t^2}\right)\cdot \frac{(-2x)}{t^3}$$

**Edit:** Note that when you wrote the formula for partial derivative of $f,$ you had $2$ dependent functions $x$ and $y,$ whereas your function is actually simpler in that you only have one dependent function $g_1.$ Drawing a tree diagram (for example, explained [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eemsilvia/math21c/disc2/discset2.html)) always helped me during undergrad while applying chain rule when dealing with partial derivatives.

Comment: I didn't see any problem for this post, just the contributor didn't define strictly their dependant and undependant variables !

Comment: @TouMou That was quite natural by definition of the function.

Comment: I think you have a minor error , you can't derivate by x twice using the derivative chain rule !

Comment: @SahibaArora Thank you for the answer. May I know whether this an application of the chain rule that I mentioned in the post or is it a different theorem?

Comment: @gune , i think there is a mistake here. If you consider y=(x,t) then you should differentiate "g1" by "y"  not by "x" .

Comment: he differentiates by x twice, this is contradictory with the chain rule.

Comment: The answer needs an update $\partial g(g_1(x,t))/\partial t=\partial g/\partial g_1\: \partial g_1/\partial t$ (pay attention to the first derivative @gune).

Comment: @gune I have edited the answer to correct it. There was a mistake in what I previously wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Answer!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the situation well ,this may help :

Define $y= g_1(x,t) = x / t^2$.

Such that $h(x,t)=g(y)=g(g_1(x,t))$.

Then $\frac{\partial g_1 }{\partial t}= \frac{\partial y }{\partial t}=\frac{-2\times t \times x }{t^4 }$,

with $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial t}=-2 \: \frac{x}{t^3}$ where $x \neq x(t)$.

We assume here that x is independant of t .

Then :

$$ \frac{\partial h(x,t) }{\partial t}= \frac{\partial g }{\partial y} \times \frac{\partial g_1 }{ \partial t } $$

And :

$$  g^{'}(y) = \frac{\partial g }{\partial y}  $$

Comment: If x is dependant on t , you could use the derivative of a product for the term y= ( x / t^2 )

Comment: @Basco , i used the latex but i don't know how to embeed it here . Also i should mention that when someone use the chain rule , we should also be prudent of the point where we evaluate the partial derivative !

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax to help you. Image only questions/answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Basco  , I updated the post.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think the op has improved his post , thus i could suggest this trivial solution :

$ h(x,t)=g(y)=g(x/t^2) $

$ \frac{\partial h(x,t) }{\partial t} = g^{'}(y(t)) \times y^{'}(t) $

$ y^{'}(t)= -2x/t^3 $

g is a function of y , and y is a function of t so it will be simple to continue the other steps ! the derivative of y is already given in the previous answer !

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Please learn to use MathJax on the site. It's a pretty basic requirement for participating, and helps keep the site more searchable, accessible, and will give your answers better consideration.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC  ,  ok !

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC , i updated the answer ! sorry because its my first time here !

Comment: No problem! I've been here four years and found out about a site convention I was getting wrong just last week. Thanks for clean-up. (Plus, Latex/MathJax is a good skill to have going forward.)